# Android: SetSpan does not apply to TextView

Tags: android, html, kotlin, spannablestring

everyone. I have two `Linear Layout`that used as `Button` in my `activity`. Inside my `Linear Layout`, I have one `TextView`. When I clicked the first or second `Linear Layout`, I am trying to change its fonts.
I have used a similar code before one of my fragments and I was working. However, I tried with it with my new `activity`, and it does not apply. I tried both `StyleSpan`and `TextAppearanceSpan`and non of them worked.

My Activiy:

```
    private fun changeFont(status: Boolean) {
    val bss = TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.CustomFont1)
    val gss = TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.CustomFont2)
    val x = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
    val y = StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)


    if (status) {
        var text = SpannableString(binding?.tvList?.text)
        text.setSpan(bss, 0, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        binding?.tvList?.text = text

        text = SpannableString(binding?.tvMap?.text)
        text.setSpan(gss, 0, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        binding?.tvMap?.text = text
    } else {
        var text = SpannableString(binding?.tvList?.text)
        text.setSpan(x, 0, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        binding?.tvList?.text = text

        text = SpannableString(binding?.tvMap?.text)
        text.setSpan(y, 0, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        binding?.tvMap?.text = text
    }
}
```

My Example `Linear Layout` Design:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llMap"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_card_round_6"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/filterBackground"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvMap"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        style="@style/CustomFont1"
                        android:text="@string/stock_toggle_btn2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

PS: I have also tried to remove text style from `XML` and `SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`on code.